# How to clear the WebBrowser from memory properly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory

In my `C#` `WinForms` application I have a `TabControl` with a `WebBrowser` control nested in it.

When the page loads (A silverlight control page) I get the Audio and video in my page just fine.

However when I call

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(myTabPage);
```

I still hear the audio playing. How do I clear the current webBrowser from memory ?

Comment: What happens when you call `Dispose` on the webbrowser instance?

Comment: Yeah I wasnt calling the dispose method. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have removed the tab page from the tab control. You have *not* destroyed the tab page, nor have you destroyed the controls it contains.

In fact, immediately after the code shown, you could do

```
tabControl2.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
```

to add that same tab page to a different tab control. Web browsers often do something similar, to enable the feature where you can drag-and-drop tabs to another window. It is also the way you temporarily make a tab page invisible, since there is no `Visible` property for the TabControl.

What you need to do is call the Dispose method for the tab page control, `myTabPage`. Normally, the framework would handle this automatically once its parent tab control is destroyed, but since you're manually removing the control from its parent container, that can't happen. You have to dispose of it manually. Modify your code to look like this:

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(myTabPage);
myTabPage.Dispose();
```

This should dispose the resources of the tab page and its child controls, including the WebBrowser.

But that won't necessarily stop the sound, at least not immediately. To ensure that happens, you need to set the WebBrowser control's [`Source` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.source.aspx) to `null`. You must do this *before* disposing of the tab page (you can't modify properties on a disposed object).

Comment: OK thanks for the tip with the sound too! very helpfull